# Babel plugin for React Native and find platform

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I wrote a babel plugin to append a custom prop into all Text elements when have a specific prop. It works fine as expected. When I inspect the element I could see the props I inserted using babel.

```
export default api => {
  const { types: t } = api

  return {
    visitor: {
      JSXOpeningElement(path) {
        const newProp = t.jSXAttribute(
          t.jSXIdentifier('favoriteColor'),
          t.stringLiteral('tomato')
        )

        path.node.attributes.push(newProp)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is, I want to insert the custom props only on iOS. I don’t want custom props to be inserted on android. Is there anyway to figure out at babel level?